# Vim: do I need to parse a language manually if I'm trying to navigate within in?

Tags: javascript, parsing, vim

I'm trying to write a few functions that will let me move around easier in JavaScript source files. The first thing that I realize is that I need to be aware of what scope my cursor is in. Looking through Vim's built in functions, I don't see anything that that does this for me automatically.

My question is, do I need to attack this problem as if Vim has no concept of scope or block structure? That is, find the first '{' and it's matching pair, define everything inbetween as scopeLevel0, find the next '{' and it's matching pair and call it scopeLevel1... etc. This seems naive to me and am wondering if Vim can allow me to access and navigate between blocks automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explain the kind of navigation you want to achieve.

Vim has the concept of scope which is defined in the syntax file for your language. There are a number of functions displaying the scope of your cursor floating here and elsewhere. The one I have in my .vimrc is:

```
function! SynStack()
    if !exists("*synstack")
        return
    endif
    echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
nnoremap <C-p> :call SynStack()<CR>
```

Navigating inside a document, specifically code, is already a great strength of Vim with text-object motions like `(` and `)` or `[(`, `[{`, `])` and `]}` or `[m` and `]m`… See `:help navigation`. Coupled with other motions like `*`, `#`, `/` and `?` or tags you already have a lot of power in your fingers.

Do you want more granularity?

For more specific needs you might want to define your own [text-objects](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects). There is a script called [textobj-user](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) designed to assist in that task. [Many special text-objects](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=textobj&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) have been created with or without this tool and made available on vim.org.

Comment: On thing I'd like to be able to do is to cycle through properties on objects. My initial thinking was that this would require a function that just search for the next instance of "someProperty:/*ignore this*/,". However the search must be constrained to whatever scope my cursor is in or it will jump around properties on child objects as well. This led me to wonder how smart Vim is about the code I'm editing and if I need to parse the document myself to determine scope or if Vim is aware of that already. From your answer it seems like the place to start is the syntax file.

Comment: For this specific example I would use `/:<CR>` to search for the next `:` and then `n` and `N` to jump from one property to the other. Or simply use TagBar/TagList. I don't think Vim understands JavaScript's notion of "scope" but you might be able to constrain your search within a pair of `{}` by setting a mark at the `{` and another at the `}` and then doing your searches between these marks.

Comment: This wouldn't fit my need, because the cursor would move between properties on child objects. However, I think the point you're ultimately making is to take advantage of cursor motions wherever possible, which is good advice.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Marks, motions and forward/backward search seem to me to be the most basic building blocks for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Can't promise this will solve your particular problem.  But for navigating source code in vim, people often use Ctags.  In particular, you might be able to use [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

If you need help getting started with ctags:

- https://superuser.com/questions/305328/gvim-what-is-ctags-and-how-do-i-use-it
- [Installing Exuberant Ctags on Windows (Vista and XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745560/installing-exhuberant-ctags-on-windows-vista-and-xp)

Also see this article on how to get it to play nicely with Javascript:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/george_v_reilly/archive/2009/03/24/exuberant-ctags-and-javascript.aspx